# Prevent Windows 7 users from canceling shutdown (disable shutdown -a)

Tags: windows, administration

From Windows 7 admin account I've set up a scheduled task with max privileges that executes a `.cmd` file which executes

```
shutdown -s -f -t 120
```

if the user happens to be logged in.

The user has only user rights but he still can cancel my Admin enforced shutdown by typing in Run box

```
shutdown -a.
```

**How do I prevent user from canceling and Admin issued shutdown?**
UAC is enabled.

Comment: Wait until the timeout has completed, and if the system hasn't shut down yet, issue another shutdown request with no timeout.

Answer (score -1):

If the logged in users are standard users, you can revoke their shutdown rights. See image for the setting where you can do so...

[image]

Comment: Will this still enable the user to shutdown the PC cause the shutdown is what I and the user both need. I just don't want the user to be able to use the PC after certain time (hence my shutdown script). Think it of as an "internet cafe pay per hour" type situation. Thanks.

Comment: No. If this setting is changed, the user will not be able to shutdown the PC.